# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable I've have been studying this one all morning

Tags: django, get

Trying to get a list of products from my database

```
def bad_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(dict(request.GET))
        my_request_data = dict(request.GET)
        new_products = my_request_data.get("new_products")
        print(my_request_data, new_products)
      if new_products[0].lower() == "true":
        print("new product")
        Products.objects.create(title=my_request_data.get('title')[0], 
   content=my_request_data.get('content')[0])
       return HttpResponse("Dont do this")
```

I keep getting :

```
if new_products[0].lower() == "true":
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
[08/Nov/2020 17:25:38] "GET /bad-view-dont-use/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67144
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
new_products = my_request_data.get("new_products")
```

is likely setting `new_products` to `None` hence your error.

But it seems like:

1. You're trying to *create* new products not *get* a list of existing products.
2. You're doing too much, why not simplify?

Here are some examples:

Creating new products (assumes new_product_titles is a parameter of the GET request and contains a list of titles):

```
def create_view(request):

    ''' creates a list of new products '''

    # unpack request:
    new_product_titles = request.GET['new_product_titles']    

    # create new products:
    for title in new_product_titles: Products.objects.create(title=title)

    # pack response:
    response = json.dumps({
        'status' : 'ok'
    })

    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Retrieving existing products (assumes product_ids is a list of ids):

```
def get_view(request):

    # get product ids or set it to an empty list:
    product_ids = request.GET['product_ids'] if 'product_ids'] in request.GET else []

    # get products:
    products = Products.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)

    # pack response:
    response = json.dumps({
        'products' : some_serializer(products)
    })

    return HttpResponse(response)
```